# Python script account generator

Tags: python, python-requests

Hi everyone I'm having a problem with my script.
Basically it creates no account and doesn't write them in my .txt file(when I open it,it's empty) but it prints emails and password.
Could you please help me?
I expect to have some working accounts and read them in my .txt file 
Hope you can help me,thanks in advance 
P.S: data_gen is a dict that contains the infos for the post request (registration)

```
times = int(input("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "]" + " - How many accounts?: ")))

Nome_completo = "testname"
Nome = Nome_completo.split()[0]
email = "test+{}@gmail.com".format(getrandbits(8))
Giorno_compleanno = random.randint(10, 27)
Mese_compleanno = random.randint(0, 12)
Anno = random.randint(1982, 2003)
Data_completa = str(str(Giorno_compleanno) + "/" + str(Mese_compleanno) + "/" + str(Anno))
password_1 = "test_1234"

s = requests.session()
r_1 = s.get(awlab_url,headers=headers)
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)

text_file = open("awlabaccounts", "r+")
def create():
    global email
    global password_1
    if str(200) in str(r.status_code):
        text_file.write(email + ":" + password_1 + "\n")
        print("Accounts successfully created!")

    else:
        print("ERROR!")
reg = s.post(url_post, data=data_gen, headers=headers)

for i in range(times):
    create()
```

Comment: Where do you even open the `text_file`?

Comment: i haven't written it but before def create(): @9000

Comment: Please post a _complete_ example that demonstrates a problem. If you re-open the file every time you run `create()` in a loop, then a new record will be written to it every time from the beginning, overwriting previous data. If you don't close the file, the data may never be written to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the text file at the end of the code.

```
for i in range(times):
    create()
text_file.close()
```